# iOS ARC Best Practices for Fire and Forget ASYNC Wrappers

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a rather simple `NSURLConnectionDelegate` wrapper class that handles simple HTTP requests for my application.

When these requests return, they call subsequent delegate methods in my main view controller class to inform me if the result was success or not.

If I take a fire-and-forget approach to using these wrappers inside a method in my view controller like so:

```
- (void) Foo {
    MySimpleRequest* request = [[MySimpleRequest alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [request send];
}
```

As soon as `Foo`'s exits, the `request` seems to be cleaned up by ARC and the subsequent delegate methods are never called.

If I move my `request` pointer to the class-level, it hangs around and succeeds.

Is that the recommended approach? Do I have to make member vars to hold on to every request or is there a way to keep its lifecycle alive until the request returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a block to return the data from the download, and have the downloader class be the delegate of the download so all the delegate methods can be contained in that class. I use a class that handles a NSURLConnection, and calls the completion block from didFailWithError or connectionDidFinishLoading:. The downloader class is deallocated after the block is executed. I call it from the view controller like this,

```
    Downloader *dl = [Downloader new];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.wswd.net/testdownloadfiles/20MB.zip"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

    [dl downloadWithRequest:request completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (data) {
            // do whatever you need to do with the raw data here
            NSLog(@"got the data");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to always keep an 'external' reference to the request. If you don't want this, I think you can just create a strong reference to self from within the `MySimpleRequest` class.

Make sure to set this to nil or you will get memory leaks obviously.